# Triggering the retrieval of a feature on a feature layer by something other than click using Open Layers 2

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I have added a feature map to my Open Layers 2 map, by using the following code. When I click a spot on the map, it correctly retrieves the feature name for that place according to the feature layer.

Code:

```
featureControl = new OpenLayers.Control.WMSGetFeatureInfo({
    url: featureLayer.url,
    title: '',
    layers: [featureLayer],
    infoFormat: 'text/xml',
    queryVisible: true
});

featureControl.events.register('getfeatureinfo', this, function (event) {
    var xml = new window.DOMParser().parseFromString(event.text, 'application/xml'),
        path = featureLayer.$featureInfoXPath,
        featureName;

    try {
        featureName = xml.evaluate(path, xml, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null).iterateNext().value;
        console.log('got the feature:', featureName)
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('error', error);
    }
});

map.addControl(featureControl);
featureControl.activate();
```

However, I would like to trigger this retrieval of the feature name on other events as well, such as when I type in an address in an input field. So I am looking for a mechanism to trigger the getfeatureinfo event by something other than "click". Is this possible? And if so, how?